# In Jira, what's the difference between "blank business" project template and "project management" template?

Tags: jira

They appear to have all the same features as far as I can tell. If I choose the PM one and discover there's something missing down the line, will I be able to add it? Or is the blank one the only one that allows you to use all the features?

I suppose that leads to a secondary question — am I able to add features to other project templates that aren't in the original template? It seems not from what I can tell, which seems very unnecessarily restrictive?